# Is there a way in tkinter to update a canvas every second until a certain time has elapsed whilst running other functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I am making a chess game with an ai in tkinter. While the ai evaluates the position, I want a Canvas to be updated with the current percentage of the maximum time that the ai is allowed to take elapsed. Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:** Here is a basic example of what my code looks like:

```
def find_move():
   piece, old_x, old_y, new_x, new_y = self.ai.make_move(args)
```

This calls a separate ai class which finds the best move. How can I get a canvas to be updated with the current percentage of a variable `self?maximum_time_for_ai` that has been elapsed. This should run until the maximum time has elapsed or the ai has finished evaluating.

Comment: tracking variable + the `after()` method should work here. That said you will need to provide some code example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I need both functions to run at the same time.

Comment: What does that have to do with your question? What functions are you talking about? You have not provided any code for us to reference.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I have edited the question.

Comment: Is your `find_move()` ran over and over during the time frame or is `self.ai.make_move(args)` doing some kind of loop checking for the best move?

Comment: self.ai.make_move loops over all the available moves to a certain depth using minimax

Comment: You will need to have something in that loop that will update the % complete on the canvas. This will likely require a tracking variable and an update statement for the canvas. You may need to pass the canvas as an argument to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how we can update a label with a timed interaction. I have set up my main class for the GUI and the 2nd class is our timer. In the 2nd class there is a method called `update_per_sec` what we are doing here is updating the % on the label that is in the canvas 10 times a second. Within this same function you can keep track of newly generated moves.

Now my example is not going to work the AI as I don't know what that code looks like but should be enough for you to modify this code to fit your needs.

```
import tkinter as tk
import string
import random


class Welcome(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("500x200")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=300, height=300, bg='white')   
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")    
        self.lbl = tk.Label(self.canvas, text="0% complete!")
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.new_move = ()
        tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=lambda: TestCode(self)).pack()


class TestCode():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.time_track = 0
        self.update_per_sec()
        self.new_move = ()

    def update_per_sec(self):
        if self.time_track != 100:
            self.master.lbl.config(text="{}% complete!".format(self.time_track))
            self.time_track += 1
            self.new_move = (random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase), random.choice(string.digits))
            self.master.after(100, self.update_per_sec)
        else:
            self.master.new_move = self.new_move
            self.master.lbl.config(text="Complete!, New move is: {}".format(self.new_move))


b = Welcome()
b.mainloop()
```